# select function in onchange() event depending on function being run

Tags: javascript, html, function, select, onchange

I have an Onchange() event which gets triggered when a change is done to a selection.  What I want to do is have two functions in the onchange() event.  But I want this to happen depending on which function is selected. So I currently have in my onchange():

```
<SELECT NAME="clothing" onChange="updateforclothingnew(); updateforclothing()">
```

I have two javascript functions: updateclass and updateclassnew

I want it so that if updateclass is run then updateforclothing() is triggered
                  if updateclassnew is run then updateforclothingnew() is triggered.

How can I put this in my onchange() event?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have co-dependent functions, why not just call them in a cascading fashion? If a updateclassnew() is run then why not call updateforclothingnew() from it?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to break out of inline JS so it's easier to read and handle.

Try this:

1 Give the select an ID.

```
<select name="clothing" id="clothing">
```

2 Assign onchange function in your script

```
var x = document.getElementById("clothing");
x.onchange = function() {
    if (x.value == "updateclass") { //or whatever condition you want to run
        updateforclothing();
    } else if (x.value == "updateclassnew") {
        updateforclothingnew();
    }
}
```

This will run the functions based on the option value selected (which is what I assume you are trying to do?)

Comment: Something like that yes, so I just have to assign any name because the value being depended on are functions, so updateclass() and updateclassnew().  The above will work I guess?  I can try it.